# A $w$ system to stabilize.

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I have the following system to be stabilized:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}\dot{w}=Aw+Bv
\\& A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 0 \\
\end{array} \right), B=\begin{pmatrix}-1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{pmatrix} 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
where $w\in \mathbb{R}^3$, and $v\in \mathbb{R}$ is the input.

The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $p(\lambda) = p(\lambda)=-\lambda^3 +3\lambda^2 +7\lambda-3$

Now I want to transform this system into a stabilized system, i.e into a new system of $ \bar{w}=\bar{A}\bar{w}+\bar{B}v$, where the eigenvalues of $\bar{A}$ have a negative real part. How do I do it? I forgot, and I can't find my notes from class.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: A simple linear transform $\bar{w}=Pw$ with $P$ nonsingular does not change the system eigenvalues. Or maybe by "transform"  you mean  taking some feedback control law of the form $v=Kw+v_0$?

Comment: I meant the second option. I think I need to use here Cayley-Hamilton on the above polynomial with $p(A)=0$, but I am not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(A,B)$ is controllable and the system has only one input you can use Ackermann's formula. Particularly you can take
$$v=Kw+v_0$$
with
$$K=-e_3^T \mathcal{C}^{-1}\alpha_d(A)$$
where $e_3$ is the third column of the identity matrix of dimension 3, 
$$\mathcal{C}:=\left[\matrix{B & AB & A^2B}\right]$$ 
the controllability matrix and 
$$a_d(s)=s^3+d_2s^2+d_1s +d_0$$
the desired polynomial whose roots you want to assign to $A+BK$. Note that $\alpha_d(A)$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix given by
$$a_d(A)=A^3+d_2A^2+d_1 A +d_0\mathbb{I}_3$$